# GRE reqs for this year and next year CS PhD

Tags: graduate-admissions, computer-science, gre

I am looking for some advice.

I have not yet taken the GRE and was looking to take advantage of this application cycle in CS PhD programs, since the GRE requirement is waived for many programs due to COVID and I think it will only decrease the strength of my application since I am not very strong on standardized tests. I have excellent grades and research experiences.

Issue is, even if I get accepted, I may defer for a year because my family is not in the financial position for me to be able to leave next year.

If GREs will not be a requirement next year either, I prefer to just apply in 2022 for entry into 2023. Does it look like it will still be the case then too? I do not want to rush my application for this year.

Comment: Would like to add to the answer by Daveguy by mentioning that it is very unlikely you will get a definitive response from universities on their GRE requirements for 2023 and later. It's quite a volatile situation.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have programs of interest?  I am kind of wondering the same thing (though I do plan on applying this cycle), however at the stage the US is at in the pandemic (presumably, where you would be planning to do your PhD in), it is more likely to vary from school/department to school/department.

Some universities may waive the GRE altogether on a permanent basis as the result of COVID, but it would be unwise to assume this for all universities, so you are best off contacting the programs that you are interested in to get a more definite answer, both for this cycle and for upcoming cycles if you do plan to defer.